# PHP Function givine IE problems

Tags: php

I have a small PHP function that is called from one of my pages.

```
function ratingDetails($uid, $align, $width) {
$queryFull = "SELECT * FROM rating WHERE uid = $uid";
$resultFull = mysql_query($queryFull);

        //START DISPLAY TABLE IF RESULTS
        if(mysql_num_rows($resultFull) > 0) {    

            echo "<table class=\"ratingTable\" align=\"center\" border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\" width=\"550\">\n";
            echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#6699cc\"><th>STARS</th><th>DATE RATED</th><th>COMMENT</th><th>RATED BY</th></tr>\n";

                while($rowFull = mysql_fetch_array($resultFull)) {
                    $rating = $rowFull['rating'];
                    $comment = $rowFull['comment'];
                    $datePosted = date("M j, Y", $rowFull['date']);
                    $rid = $rowFull['raterID'];
                    $rater = getUsername($rid);

                    //SHOW STARS
                    if($rating == 0) { $stars = "notYet.jpg"; }
                    if($rating == 1) { $stars = "starOne.jpg"; }
                    if($rating == 1.5) { $stars = "starOneHalf.jpg"; }
                    if($rating == 2) { $stars = "starTwo.jpg"; }
                    if($rating == 2.5) { $stars = "starTwoHalf.jpg"; }
                    if($rating == 3) { $stars = "starThree.jpg"; }
                    if($rating == 3.5) { $stars = "starThreeHalf.jpg"; }
                    if($rating == 4) { $stars = "starFour.jpg"; }
                    if($rating == 4.5) { $stars = "starFourHalf.jpg"; }
                    if($rating == 5) { $stars = "starFive.jpg"; }

                    //DISPLAY IT ALL
                    echo "<tr><td width=\"10\"><img src=\"/images/rating/$stars\" width=\"105\" height=\"20\" /></td>";
                    echo "<td width=\"75\" align=\"center\">$datePosted</td><td>$comment</td><td width=\"85\">$rater</td></tr>\n";
                }//END WHILE
                echo "</table>\n";
        } //END IF
        else {
            echo "<table class=\"ratingTable\" align=\"center\" border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"8\" width=\"550\">\n";
            echo "<tr><td align=\"center\"><span class=\"blue\">NO REVIEWS OR RATINGS FOR THIS DISTRIBUTOR</span></td></tr></table>\n";    

        }        //END IF ELSE
```

}

But when it runs in IE (7 or 8), it throws this error:

> A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly.  Bla bla bla...

I call this function from two pages and both cause the same error. If I remove the call from the page, the page loads fine.

There is no javascript involved with the pages in question...

***Help, help, help...  I don't have much hair left...***

Rick

Comment: How many rows the query returns?

Comment: Do you have any Flash (.swf) files loading on these pages?

Comment: I guess, you use "gigabyte" table to fetch. Have you tried to load your page with other browsers such as Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari?

Comment: Just testing site right now.  Only 15 rows in the table this function calls.  No flash on the site.  Works great in all browsers, except IE.  Tried 7 and 8, same results.

Comment: The first thing you should do is save the final output as a pure html page and then debug that static page until you track down the culprit. In addition, there is no guarantee that the problem is in the function you listed, since it is not the complete output, and the problem MAY lie elsewhere in the body of the HTML document.

Comment: The reason I'm leaning towards this function being the bad-guy is, it is called from two different pages.  If I remove just this single function call, the page loads fine.  One of the pages is it's own complete page, while the other is an 'include' inside a php page.  I appreciate all the input! Keep it coming!!!

Comment: I've traced it down (so far) to these two lines...
echo "<table class=\"ratingTable\" align=\"center\" border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\" width=\"550\">\n";
            echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#6699cc\"><th>STARS</th><th>DATE RATED</th><th>COMMENT</th><th>RATED BY</th></tr>\n";
 Now, i've gotta figure out what is wrong with these lines...

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that it's taking a long time to execute your script. IE is waiting for output from the server but it's taking a long time.

You may want to try either a call to flush() every row (or maybe every 25 rows using the modulus operator) or using ob_implicit_flush() to turn on implicit flushing. That way you have data continually coming back to the browser (I assume you have a huge amount of data). You probably will also need to call set_timeout(0) to disable the 30 second time limit on your script.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance!
But, I'm still in development, and only have 15 or so records in MySQL database.  Even so, I'm going to look into the flush() and set_timeout() functions you recommended.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If you only have 15 records then you're getting hung up somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is get rid of all those IF statements for the stars, either using an array for them or a switch statement, either of which would reduce the processing required for your script. An array would be my approach. Your code would look something like the following:

```
function ratingDetails($uid, $align, $width) {
```

$queryFull = "SELECT * FROM rating WHERE uid = $uid";
$resultFull = mysql_query($queryFull);

// Declare the array for the stars.
$astars = array(
        0=> "notYet.jpg", 
        1=> "starOne.jpg", 
        1.5=> "starOneHalf.jpg", 
        2=> "starTwo.jpg", 
        2.5=> "starTwoHalf.jpg", 
        3=> "starThree.jpg", 
        3.5=> "starThreeHalf.jpg", 
        4=> "starFour.jpg", 
        4.5=> "starFourHalf.jpg", 
        5=> "starFive.jpg"
    );

```
    //START DISPLAY TABLE IF RESULTS
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultFull) > 0) {    

        echo "<table class=\"ratingTable\" align=\"center\" border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\" width=\"550\">\n";
        echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#6699cc\"><th>STARS</th><th>DATE RATED</th><th>COMMENT</th><th>RATED BY</th></tr>\n";

            while($rowFull = mysql_fetch_array($resultFull)) {
                $rating = $rowFull['rating'];
                $comment = $rowFull['comment'];
                $datePosted = date("M j, Y", $rowFull['date']);
                $rid = $rowFull['raterID'];
                $rater = getUsername($rid);
                $stars = $astars[$rating];

                //DISPLAY IT ALL
                echo "<tr><td width=\"10\"><img src=\"/images/rating/$stars\" width=\"105\" height=\"20\" /></td>";
                echo "<td width=\"75\" align=\"center\">$datePosted</td><td>$comment</td><td width=\"85\">$rater</td></tr>\n";
            }//END WHILE
            echo "</table>\n";
    } //END IF
    else {
        echo "<table class=\"ratingTable\" align=\"center\" border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"8\" width=\"550\">\n";
        echo "<tr><td align=\"center\"><span class=\"blue\">NO REVIEWS OR RATINGS FOR THIS DISTRIBUTOR</span></td></tr></table>\n";    

    }        //END IF ELSE
```

The decimals may cause a problem in the array; if so, you can enclose the keys in quotes; e.g., `"1.5"=>"starOneHalf.jpg"`

The other thing you could do is create a variable for the HTML output instead of echoing the output every line, and then just echo the output at the end.

Comment: I originally had it setup with a switch, but changed it to the IF to see if that was my problem.  Probably going to go back to the switch once I figure out the main cause of my problem...   Also tried the variable $table = "..." then an echo before the return.  Didn't seem to have an effect, either way.  I do appreciate the input!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem...
The table within my function was assigned a css class.  This particular css class contained a behavior, which called PIE.htc.  Apparently, this caused some sort of IE melt down whenever it was called.  I removed PIE (bummer, no more rounded corners or shadows in IE) and my problem is solved!!!

Thanks to everyone who provided assistance along the way!!!